# How to use hidden field value in script using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have in html page like

```
<input type="hidden" id="disqusId"  ng-value="disqusId">
```

and I am using that value in script in same html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'lingaraj';
    var disqus_identifier =  document.getElementById("disqusId").value;//its not getting value
    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {`enter code here`
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Your code writing  in jquery and your tag is angularjs.  clarify about this.

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs not jquery.

```
         <input type="hidden" id="disqusId"   ng-model="disqusId">
```

and in your js file .

```
console.log($scope.disqusId);
```

Comment: Actually $scope.discusId is set in Controller and in html <input type="hidden" id="disqusId"  ng-value="disqusId"> in that same page i added above script ,how can i assign that hidden value to var disqus_identifier

Answer (score 1):

To Retrieve

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByName('disqusId'][0]).val();
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="disqusId" ng-init="disqusId='your desired value'" ng-model="disqusId">
```

To bind data then you can use anyone of the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="disqusId" value="{{disqusId}}" /> 


<input type="hidden" name="disqusId" ng-value="disqusId" />
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but not working .....                                                                                                            As i mentioned in my question my controller in controller.js and declared and assigned $scope.disqusId  and <input type="hidden" ng-value ="{{disqusId}}" /> and script in same html page, how can i get the value of this and assign to var disqus_identifier =  ? (here how to get value of disqusId) in script not in controller.js , i tried using document.getElementById('disqusId').value but not getting value

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs - use ng-model.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="disqusId" name="disqusId"  ng-model="disqusId">
```

in your controller try to print in console ->

```
`console.log($scope.disqusId);
```

to me with angular i dont see the necessity to have a hidden value as you can just save in model / $scope

eg : you have save all your form in $scope.form and extract all model related to it

> $scope.form.hiddenValue

i have prepared something in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KC3qki?p=preview)